# How to change the greeter background in elementary OS juno

Tags: greeter

I can not find any settings regarding changing the background image in the new greeter.

Currently it shows a grey background with a user card in the middle.

Is there any way to set a preferred background image instead of the default grey colored background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this stage it's not configurable and has been designed like that. I did see on Reddit quite a few remarks and suggestions regarding that same issue. Head over to teh sub-reddit here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/